# My question is about datagrid expandable row

Tags: vmware-clarity

How can I listen to the event when user clicks on row caret to either expand/close the row detail area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use de-sugard syntax for the `*clrIfExpanded` directive like so:

```
  <clr-datagrid>
    <clr-dg-column>Col1</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column>Col2</clr-dg-column>

    <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let item of [1,2,3,4,5]">
      <clr-dg-cell>Item {{item}}</clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-cell>Item * Item ({{item*item}})</clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-dg-row-detail clrIfExpanded (clrIfExpandedChange)="rowChange($event)">
        details
      </clr-dg-row-detail>
    </clr-dg-row>
  </clr-datagrid>
```

Here is a working stackblitz that logs the change each time the row is opened or closed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-55617551-click-handler-for-datagrid-row-details

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. Would you mind accepting the answer if it works for you?